# Google sheets rounds 1,00000000001 to 1

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to prevent rounding of 1,00000000001 in Google sheets? When I input 1,0000000001 (10 digits after comma) it is good, but with 11 digits after comma it is rounding to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is only rounding the display**. It is actually keeping 15 (or so) digits of accuracy. You can see this if you click on that cell that shows "1" but look at the contents bar that shows what's actually in that cell. You can still use that value in calculations and it will be using 1.0000000001 and not 1.

You can also increase the number of decimals shown by using the button "Increase decimal digits." Increasing it beyond 15 decimals, though, and you will start to see the limitation of IEEE753 floating point representation.

Google sheets (and spreadsheets in general) use IEEE753 rep of numbers:

https://support.google.com/docs/thread/155960403/is-a-limit-on-how-much-google-sheets-will-recognize-past-15-decimal-places-on-an-if-function?hl=en

If you need to work with values like that, you might want to keep your numbers as strings and perform your own string processing to extract the digits you want from whatever positions you want.